# How to get the count of records in the DataSource of the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `grid view` already binded with model, Now I want to get the count of the rows in this `GridView's Datatable` ? not on the page count.

Comment: Do you have some example source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the GridView's DataSource to DataTable or DataView and then count the rows.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable) gridView.DataSource; 
int count = dt.Rows.Count;
```

But this will be available only at the time of binding, not across the postback.

To get the row count on post back, you can store the `DataTable` or its row count in session before binding it to the GridView.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataSourceTable();
Session["RowsCount"] = dt.Rows.Count;
Session["DataTable"] = dt; //Should be avoided since session are per user. 
gridView.DataSource = dt;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Later you can access the `Count` from the session.

Comment: 1) In `GridView1_DataBinding()` and `GridView1_DataBound()`, both GridView1.DataSource is Nothing (in VB.NET). Sorry how can you get the count from nothing? (For sure the GridView1 shows several pages.)
2) I don't want to write my `GetDatasourceTable()`. I just rely on DataSource, how can I get the total number of records?

Answer (score 8):

You can cast datasource in collection and then count as follow

```
var count = ((ICollection<T>)GridView.DataSource).Count;
```

Or if you have datatable as source then

```
DataTable dt = gridView.DataSource as DataTable; 
 int count = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: I like the single line solution.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
yourDataTable.Rows.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
textBox1.Text = gridView1.RowCount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
DataView MyDV = (DataView)SqldatasourceName.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
MyDV.RowFilter = SqldatasourceName.FilterExpression;
int RecordCount = MyDV.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following.

Created an event on Gridview Databound with the following. This updates a label with the Record count each time the gridview is bound.

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecordCountLbl.Text = "Record Count: "+ GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```